# Finding nearest pixel in defined color space - quick implementation using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, performance, euclidean-distance

I have been working on a task, where I implemented median cut for image quantization – representing the whole image by only limited set of pixels. I implemented the algorithm and now I am trying to implement the part, where I assign each pixel to a representant from the set found by median cut. So, I have variable 'color_space', which is 2d ndarray of shape (n,3), where n is the number of representatives. Then I have variable 'img', which is the original image of shape (rows, columns, 3).

Now I want to find the nearest pixel (bin) for each pixel from the image based on euclidean distance. I was able to come with this solution:

```
    for row in range(img.shape[0]):
       for column in range(img.shape[1]):
          img[row][column] = color_space[np.linalg.norm(color_space - img[row][column], axis=1).argmin()]
```

What it does is, that for each pixel from the image, it computes the vector if distances from each of the bins and then it takes the closest one.
Problem is, that this solution is quite slow and I would like to vectorize it - instead of getting vector for each pixel, I would like to get a matrix, where for example first row would be the first vector of distances computed in my code etc...

This problem could be converted into a problem, where I want to do a matrix multiplication, but instead of getting dot product of two vectors, I would get their euclidean distance. Is there some good approach to such problems? Some general solution in numpy, if we want to do 'matrix multiplication' in numpy, but the function Rn x Rn -> R does not need to be dot product, but for example euclidean distance. Of course, for the multiplication, the original image should be resized to (row*columns, 3), but that is a detail.

I have been studying the documentation and searching internet, but didn't find any good approach.

Please note that I don't want others to solve my assignment, the solution I came up with is totally ok, I am just curious whether I could speed it up as I try to learn numpy properly.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: In your converted problem, the two matrices are not of the same size right? Since the representatives have a smaller size.

Comment: No they are not, but they still can be multiplied as they share the '3' dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is MWE for vectorizing your problem. See comments for explanation.

```
import numpy

# these are just random array declaration to work with. 
image = numpy.random.rand(32, 32, 3)
color_space = numpy.random.rand(10,3)

# your code. I modified it to pick indexes
result = numpy.zeros((32,32))
for row in range(image.shape[0]):
    for column in range(image.shape[1]):
        result[row][column] = numpy.linalg.norm(color_space - image[row][column], axis=1).argmin()
result = result.astype(numpy.int)

# here we reshape for broadcasting correctly. 
image = image.reshape(1,32,32,3)
color_space = color_space.reshape(10, 1,1,3)

# compute the norm on last axis, which is RGB values
result_norm = numpy.linalg.norm(image-color_space, axis=3)

# now compute the vectorized argmin 
result_vectorized = result_norm.argmin(axis=0)

print(numpy.allclose(result, result_vectorized))
```

Eventually, you can get the correct solution by doing `color_space[result]`. You may have to remove the extra dimensions that you add in color space to get correct shapes in this final operation.

Comment: But this still relies on double indexing and for-loops. The whole point of `numpy` is that it eliminates the need for for-loops.

Comment: @victor__von__doom no the answer was only comparing results

Comment: yes, the actual code only starts after the `# here we reshape for broadcasting correctly.` comment.

Comment: @UmangGupta yep, didn't see that at first

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this solution. Took me a bit longer to make it work in my code. The performance is amazing, my solution takes usually more than 10 s, yours takes around 0.1 s. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach might be a bit more *numpy-ish/pythonic*:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import *
from numpy import linalg as LA

# assume color_space is defined as a constant somewhere above and is of shape (n,3)

nearest_pixel_idxs: Callable[[np.ndarray], int] = lambda rgb: return LA.norm(color_space - rgb, axis=1).argmin()

img: np.ndarray = color_space[np.apply_along_axis(nearest_pixel_idxs, 1, img.reshape((-1, 3)))]
```

Why this solution might be more efficient:

- It relies on the parallelizable `apply_along_axis` function `nearest_pixel_idxs()` rather than the nested for-loops. This is made possible by reshaping `img` and thereby removing the need for double indexing.
- It avoids repeated writes into `color_space` by only indexing into it once at the very end.

Let me know if you would like me to go into greater depth on any of this - happy to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick solution! I compared yours solution to mine on a 512 x 768 image. Yours took, 11.5 s and mine took 12.2 s. Not a radical improvement in terms of performance, but definitely nicer solution. The function apply_along_axis was something I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @TobyV. Glad you found it useful! If you feel it met your needs, would you mind confirming it as the correct answer by hitting the green checkmark at the top left? Thanks!

Comment: @TobyV. Also, just out of curiousity, does using `lambda rgb: return  np.argpartition(LA.norm(color_space - rgb, axis=1), 0)[0]` run any faster?

Answer (score 0):

You could first broadcast to get all the combinations and then calculate each norm. You could then pick the smallest from there.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [2,3,4],
              [3,4,5]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [3,4,5]])
a = np.repeat(a.reshape(a.shape[0],1,3), b.shape[0], axis = 1)
b = np.repeat(b.reshape(1,b.shape[0],3), a.shape[0], axis = 0)
np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis = 2)
```

Each row of the result represents the distance of the row in `a` to each of the representatives in `b`

```
array([[0.        , 3.46410162],
       [1.73205081, 1.73205081],
       [3.46410162, 0.        ]])
```

You can then use `argmin` to get the final results.

IMO it is better to use (what @Umang Gupta proposed) numpy's automatic broadcasting than using `repeat`.